# NoClassDefFoundError - ClassLoaderDelegate - Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am new to Java Hibernate. I setup a dynamic web project in eclipse and trying to insert a row in mysql db. I am getting the following error when I run my code on server.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate
>       org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
>       org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
>       org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:655)

My hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name='connection.driver_class'>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name='connection.url'>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bornscientific</property>
    <property name='connection.username'>root</property>
    <property name='connection.password'></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name='connection.pool_size'>1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name='dialect'>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name='show_sql'>true</property>

    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping class="com.bornscientific.persistence.beans.Tags"/>

</session-factory>
```

My entity class

```
package com.bornscientific.persistence.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TAGS")
public class Tags implements Serializable
{

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Tags()
    {

    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq1",sequenceName="HIB_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="seq1")
    @Column(name = "TAG_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME", unique = true, length = 100, nullable = false)
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And my main method is

```
public static void test() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();

            Tags tags = new Tags();
            tags.setName("TAG_1");

            session.save(tags);
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("Saved successfully...");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //System.out.println(e)
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
    package com.bornscientific.persistence;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

And this is the library referenced.
[image]

Please help me fix this issue. I have searched through google and could not find a solution.

Comment: Your referenced libraries appear mismatched.  For example, I see version 4.0.4.Final of `hibernate-commons-annotations` and version 5.0.0.Final of `hibernate-core`.  Version 5.0.0 of the annotations package ships with Hibernate 5.0.0.  I also see `hibernate-jpa-2.0` (version 1.0.0.Final), whereas it is `hibernate-jpa-2.1` that ships with Hibernate 5.0.0.  There may be other mismatches.  It seems likely that these mismatches explain your problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That was the problem. I added correct versions of jars and it works good now. Thank you so much.