# Enested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. When I run my project, I'm getting below exceptions. Please help me to resolve this.

> Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at the comments - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000878/noclassdeffounderror-classloaderdelegate-hibernate

Comment: You need to add a full stack trace, Hibernate version, a list of your libraries or `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem is, obviously, with your mess of libraries.

You use Hibernate 5 so you need `hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar`. The class `ClassLoaderDelegate` resides in this jar.

You don't need `hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar`,`hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar` (it is for an old version of Hibernate), `javaee-api-7.0.jar` (`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` is similar). Check other jars too. Or the best way to use Maven or Gradle, or download all dependencies for Hibernate 5

[Hibernate ORM Releases](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/)